# How do I find out what Python implementation I am using?

Tags: python, language-implementation

Is there a simple way, like one command, that will enable me to find what Python implementation I am using (CPython, JPython, etc.)?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.implementation

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: Why exactly does it matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`platform.python_implementation()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.python_implementation):

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.python_implementation()
'CPython'
```